# Problem with Firebase Storage reference in Swift program

Tags: swift, firebase, storage

I am an iOS App developer using Swift. I opened Firebase Storage today and proceeded step by step in accordance with the help document. I can already view the txt file I uploaded on web browser with the url: "https://storage.googleapis.com/my_bucket_name/story_001.txt". But I encountered difficulty in accessing the txt file in the App. I think the problem lies in the generation of the reference. Here is my code:

```
let ref = Storage.storage().reference();
let txt_ref = ref.child("gs://my_bucket_name").child("story_001.txt");
print(txt_ref.fullPath);
txt_ref.getMetadata{ metadata, error in
    if let err = error { print("Failed to get metadata."); }
    else{ print("Metadata: \(metadata)"); }
}
```

I get the following output from console:

```
gs:/my_bucket_name/story_001.txt
Failed to get metadata.
```

The two slashes after "gs:" become one slash. I think the problem should come from here.
How can I solve it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may able to use the `reference withPath:` API like

```
let ref = Storage.storage().reference(withPath:"my_bucket_name")
let txt_ref = ref.child("story_001.txt")
```

See additional examples in these [integration tests](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/FirebaseStorage/Tests/SwiftIntegration/StorageIntegration.swift).

Comment: Paul, Thanks for your reply. I tried your method and print err.localizedDescription, it says: "Object gs:/my_bucket_name/story_001.txt does not exist.", failed still.